# Swig pass Python datetime object to C++

Tags: python, swig, cpython

I have a function in C++ that is passed a `uint64_t` as nanoseconds from epoch. I have wrapped this number in an object `DateTime` as in

```cpp
struct DateTime {
    uint64_t epochns;
};
void print( DateTime ts );
```

Obviously the function is not exactly `print` as I could use Python's own for this purpose.

It is important that I use it seamlessly with Python datetime objects as in

```py
print( datetime(1985,7,1) )
```

I'm unsure how to write a typemap that achieves this requirement.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method `datetime.timestamp` on the object to return the epoch in seconds then multiply by 1E6 to get to microseconds and round to integer. Then multiply again by 1000 to get to nanoseconds.

```c
%typemap(in)  DateTime
{
    PyObject* str = PyString_FromString( "timestamp" );
    PyObject* obj = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs( $input, str, nullptr );
    $1.epochns = int64_t(PyFloat_AsDouble( obj )*1000000)*1000LL;
    Py_XDECREF( obj );
    Py_XDECREF( str );
}
```

The intermediate multiplication is necessary as if you multiply straight by 1E9 you will have unrounded garbage in the nanoseconds part.

**UPDATE 9/24/2022**
I ended up with this extended code that takes datetime, time and timedelta as well.  Also the above code will take everything as local timezone, which was something I did not want. I wanted the time to be all in UTC with no timezone meddling.

In my swig file:

```
%typemap(in)  hb::DateTime
{
    $1.epochns = hb::getEpochNanos( $input );
}
```

Somewhere in my c++ sources:

```cpp
int64_t getEpochNanos(PyObject* obj) {
    if (PyDateTime_CheckExact(obj) || PyDate_CheckExact(obj)) {
        int64_t usecs = PyDateTime_DATE_GET_MICROSECOND(obj);
        struct tm tms;
        memset(&tms, 0, sizeof(tms));
        tms.tm_wday = -1;
        tms.tm_year = PyDateTime_GET_YEAR(obj) - 1900;
        tms.tm_mon = PyDateTime_GET_MONTH(obj) - 1;
        tms.tm_mday = PyDateTime_GET_DAY(obj);
        tms.tm_hour = PyDateTime_DATE_GET_HOUR(obj);
        tms.tm_min = PyDateTime_DATE_GET_MINUTE(obj);
        tms.tm_sec = PyDateTime_DATE_GET_SECOND(obj);
        time_t tt = timegm(&tms);
        if (tms.tm_wday == -1) return 0;
        return int64_t(tt) * 1000000000LL + usecs * 1000;
    } else if (PyTime_Check(obj)) {
        int64_t usecs = PyDateTime_TIME_GET_MICROSECOND(obj);
        int64_t hour = PyDateTime_TIME_GET_HOUR(obj);
        int64_t min = PyDateTime_TIME_GET_MINUTE(obj);
        int64_t sec = PyDateTime_TIME_GET_SECOND(obj);
        return int64_t(((hour * 60) + min) * 60 + sec) * 1000000000LL + usecs * 1000;
    } else if (PyDelta_Check(obj)) {
        int64_t usecs = PyDateTime_DELTA_GET_MICROSECONDS(obj);
        int64_t days = PyDateTime_DELTA_GET_DAYS(obj);
        int64_t sec = PyDateTime_DELTA_GET_SECONDS(obj);
        return int64_t(days * 86400 + sec) * 1000000000LL + usecs * 1000;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Notice I set `-1` as a sentinel in wday. The fact is that `-1` is a valid epoch (1 day before epoch) so the only way to check if the call failed was to set the `wday` to minus one and check it afterwards. If the call is successful, `wday` would be set to the week day (0 to 6) accordingly but not if it fails.

Comment: You can use `PyObject_CallMethod($input, "timestamp", nullptr)` and save a few lines.  Don't forget to check `obj` for NULL in case a non-datetime object is passed.